# Adding a column to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe like this:

```
case    is1     is5     is10    im1     im5     im10
686     0.1406  0.2997  0.1490  0.1339  0.1350  0.1417
950     0.1602  0.3448  0.1719  0.0884  0.0962  0.1385
1005    0.1641  0.2606  0.1507  0.1306  0.1613  0.1328
1005    0.1456  0.3097  0.1825  0.1116  0.1295  0.1211
```

I'd like to add a 8th column using a formula, say

```
const1*is1+const2*is2+...const6*im10
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will probably work

```
df['new col']=const1*df['is1']+.....+const6*df['im10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df['8thcol'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[' is1'] + x[' is5'] + x[' is10'] + \
                                x['im1'] + x['im5']+ x['im10'], axis=1)
const = 5 # any constant value
df['8thcol']  = df.8thcol * const 

df
```